# Detecting browser print event happens two different ways in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I am currently using the most up-to-date version of Chrome (43.0.2357.130), and am experiencing a difference in printing functionality when calling print from `window.print()` vs using ⌘P.

When printing using `window.print()` it outputs to the console correctly. It outputs `Before Print` when the print dialog is opened, and `After Print` when the dialog is closed.

However, when using the Chrome menu, or ⌘P to print, it logs both `Before Print`, and `After Print` to the console when the print dialog opens.

Here is the code I am using, which works well in other browsers.

```
function beforePrint() {
    console.log('Before Print');
}

function afterPrint() {
    console.log('After Print');
}

if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function (mql) {
        (mql.matches) ? beforePrint() : afterPrint();
    });
}
else {
    // basically a fallback for < IE11
    window.addEventListener('beforeprint', beforePrint, false);
    window.addEventListener('afterprint', afterPrint, false);
}
```

Once again for clarity as if this was the console:

This is the output I expect:

```
> window.print()
  Before Print
  // Print Dialog is now open, I press cancel to close dialog
  After Print
```

This is the output I get when I use ⌘P or the menu to start print:

```
  Before Print
  After Print
  // Print Dialog is now open, but it is occurring in the wrong place
```

Is this a bug in Chrome, or is there another way to capture the event correctly?

Just for reference, here is the [Can I Use support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia) for `matchMedia`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is probably just a bug with Chrome. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422883