# override the content of javascript window.print

Tags: javascript

I want to override the behavior of window.print, like if the dom contains a table I don't want certain rows to be printed.

I referred to the below stack overflow answer on how to hack the javacript event, but not sure how I can update the dom content for the print
[JavaScript: Overriding alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert)

Can anyone throw some light into this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can run your own special JavaScript by overriding the `window.print` function. However, this is a different flow than someone clicking print from the navigation bar.

`window.print` is the print flow as launched by the application.

```
var oldPrintFunction = window.print;

window.print = function () {
    console.log('Gonna do some special stuff');
    oldPrintFunction();
};
```

---

#### Working with user driven print events and programmed print events:

I had to go look this up as I had something I wrote a long time ago that did something similar, and it seems that I found it. This code watches for the media change to go to `print`.

```
function beforePrint() {
    console.log('Do something special before print');
}

function afterPrint() {
    console.log('Do something after print');
}

if (window.matchMedia) {
    window.matchMedia('print').addListener(function (mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            beforePrint();
        }
        else {
            afterPrint();
        }
    });
}
// For IE, does not attach in browsers that do not support these events
window.addEventListener('beforeprint', beforePrint, false);
window.addEventListener('afterprint', afterPrint, false);
```

This will run whatever is in the `beforePrint` function for calling `window.print()`, or the user chooses to print using a browser flow (command+p, file->print), etc.

**Please note:** The `afterprint` has a bug in Chrome, see my [StackOverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008434/detecting-browser-print-event-happens-two-different-ways-in-chrome)

Comment: This is the approach I was going to suggest.

Comment: Can i access any variable inside window.print which contains all the values inside the dom which i can alter and later pass it to print

Comment: @Akash, no, you can't read into the print stream. However, you could run down the DOM that is going to be printed, and set the rows or whatever you don't want to be printed to `display: none`, and then when the print job finishes, run over those rows again and reset the display. I'll add how to watch for the print job to be "finished"

Comment: Thanks @KevBot for the detailed response.

Answer (score 3):

use media queries to add styles that will only be applied to the printed version of the page...

```
@media print {
   #idOdTableNotToPrint{ display:none; }
}
```

This will hide the table with id of `idOdTableNotToPrint` only when the page is printed.

Or if you want to create a whole new stylesheet for it, you can specify that the CSS is for print only in the `<link>` tag by adding a `media='print'` attribute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print_styles.css" media='print'/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot, Since i am rendering my dom using react based on certain conditions, need to work on a logic on how to dynamically apply it. Thanks for the help. :)