# matchMedia & beforeprint not triggering on window.print

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to prevent to have to hide/show a bunch of elements with CSS and instead render them only when printing, to do so I'm using this pattern:

```
const beforePrint = () => { console.log('beforePrint') };
const afterPrint = () => { console.log('afterPrint') };

if (window.matchMedia) {
  const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
  mediaQueryList.addListener((mql) => {
    if (mql.matches) {
      beforePrint();
    } else {
      afterPrint();
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener('beforeprint', this.handleBeforePrint);
window.addEventListener('afterprint', this.handleAfterPrint);
```

The `console.log` are triggered as expected but when I'm rendering elements instead of doing a `console.log`, it works only when the user does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and not when `window.print` is triggered.

Here is my example https://pw74zpl44x.codesandbox.io/ and the code (in React but it doesn't matter) https://codesandbox.io/s/pw74zpl44x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting browser print event happens two different ways in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008434/detecting-browser-print-event-happens-two-different-ways-in-chrome)

Comment: I have the issue on Firefox too